# Рабочий пример отправки файла средствами PHP

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

Подскажите рабочий пример с отправкой файла (вложения) из формы на почту.
В интернете много примеров, но всё сводится либо к большой библиотеке PHPMailer, либо к нерабочим примерам. Что это за тайная магия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот мой рабочий вариант:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" />
    <input type="text" name="sender" placeholder="Куда мне ответить ( ваша почта )" />
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Тема сообщения" />
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="emailto" value="example@mail.ru" />
    <input type="file" name="toupload" />   
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
  function mailX($emailfrom, $emailto, $subject, $message = "Текст сообщения которое будет отправлено",$filename)
  {
        $un = strtoupper(uniqid(time()));
        $headers = "From: $emailfrom <noreply@site.mail>\n";
        $headers .= "To: $emailto\n";
        $headers .= "Subject: $subject\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHPMail Tool\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type:multipart/mixed;";
        $headers .= "boundary=\"----------".$un."\"\n\n";
        $message .= "------------".$un."\nContent-Type:text/html;\n";
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n$text\n\n";
        $f = fopen($filename,"rb");
        $message .= "------------".$un."\n";
        $message .= "Content-Type: application/octetstream;";
        $message .= "name=\"".basename($filename)."\"\n";
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n";
        $message .= "Content-Disposition:attachment;";
        $message .= "filename=\"".basename($filename)."\"\n\n";
        $message .= chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($f,filesize($filename))))."\n";

        mail($emailto, $subject, $message, $headers, $emailfrom);
  }
  if ( ISSET($_POST['submit']) )
    {
      //Сделаем более-менее прилежным вид письма
      $message = 'Привет. На твой ящик пришло письмо от '.$_POST['name'].'
      '.($_POST['sender']).' !<br/>
      С таким содержанием '.$_POST['message'];
      mailX('Форма обратной связи', $_POST['emailto'], $_POST['subject'],$message, $_FILES['toupload']['name']);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Может я опять что-то не так делаю?
Здесь заменил почту на свою (<input type="hidden" name="emailto" value="..." />), саму форму поместил в index.html
PHP код залил в файл mail.php.
Всё это залил на хост и ничего не работает и ошибки выдает после нажатия кнопки "отправить".

Comment: @Александр какие ошибки выдаёт? Можно в студию?

Comment: А action=" *.php " надо добавлять же? Тогда выдает ошибки такого плана:
Warning: fopen(РїСЂРёРІРµС‚.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u842147903/public_html/mail.php on line 14

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for РїСЂРёРІРµС‚.txt in /home/u842147903/public_html/mail.php on line 21

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u842147903/public_html/mail.php on line 21

Если без action=" *.php " то ошибок нет. Но и в том и в том случае не работает почему-то, пробовал на разные почты. В итоге один раз всё же пришло, больше нет

Comment: @Александр если php файл выносишь отдельно, то action=" mail.php " надо.